# Search engine ranking of paginated categories, subcategories and tag pages

Tags: seo, search-engines, googlebot, pagination

Suppose we have an E-commerce domain with the following structure:

1. `domain/items` - contains all items.
2. `domain/items/category` - contains a narrower spectrum of results than above.
3. `domain/items/category/subcategory` - contains a narrower spectrum of results than above.

All these URLs listing items for sell can have pagination (with query string parameter `?page=X`, where X is a page number).

My question is:

In order to obtain the best results in SEO (especially Google), how they should be indexed?

It is possible to index them by:

1. Providing "view all link" and including `rel="canonical"` link to "view all link" to all paginated pages.
2. Implementing canonical `rel="prev"` and `rel="next"` links.

But each narrower category/subcategory contains same items as broader category. Would search ranking algorithm give penalty for duplicate content?

What if we have paginated `domain/tag/[tag]`, where `[tag]` is a word given to item by users. Should we index those pages too or exclude them from indexing because it is already indexed in items/category or subcategory?

I will appreciate any useful information regarding this issue.